# Postgresql table manipulation

Tags: postgresql

I am very very new to databases and I need some help figuring out how to create a query that I need.

I have a table with columns: date, product_id, signal.  There are only 5 products at the moment but can grow but will never be more than 15. Each product only takes up 1000-2000 rows and each product will only grow by one row per day.
I am trying to figure out a query that will present the data as follows:

| date | product_name1 | product_name2 | product_name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 0 (signal value of that day) | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

I pretty much need a row for each date that will have each product_name as the column name and the values will be the signal of that day for that product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a JSON object per day like {"date":"2022-01-01", "product_name_1": 0, ...}? This would be a very simple and effective query.

Comment: Do you know every possible `product_name` to define the columns ahead of time or does that change over time and the sql has to figure it out dynamically? If it changes, this is called a "Dynamic Pivot" and it's a pretty ugly thing to make a database do. Excel or similar data presentation/dataviz applications is the place to do this.

Comment: @JNevill The product names will change over time.  I had a feeling that this would be a pain to do.